# How can i prevent gdb from attaching to an exe?

Tags: linux, gdb

I'd like to prevent would-be hackers from attaching to my binary on Linux systems.  I see that ptrace DENY_ATTACH can be used on OSX.  Is there such option that can be used on linux?  How about on Windows?

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 1):

Such a system call requires kernel support.  Even if it existed in Linux, it would be fairly easy to disable by compiling your own kernel.

Answer (score 0):

In linux, ptrace returns -1 if the process is being ptraced.

So, one solution would be, inside your program, try to attach to your process, and if you get a -1, you will know that the program is being ptraced.